# C# Textbox data binding with DataSet

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a `TextBox` to which I have given a `DataBinding` as follows:

```
    txtCompanyAddress.DataBindings.Add("Text", CompanyDetailsDataSet, 
"CompanyDetails.CompanyAddress");
```

Also I have added a BindingManagerBase object on form as below:

```
protected BindingManagerBase BindingManager
        {
            get
            {
                return this.BindingContext[CompanyDetailsDataSet, "CompanyDetails"];
            }
        }
```

I have a cancel button on my form which cancels the changes. When I update the value in `txtCompanyAddress` and hit cancel, I call `BindingManager.CancelCurrentEdit();` but the text box value does not change to old one.

Is this any data bindings issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your bindings will not refresh automatically with this setup you need to change the mode when data binding is updated

```
          txtCompanyAddress.DataBindings.Add("Text", CompanyDetailsDataSet,"CompanyDetails.CompanyAddress", true,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Also you haven't posted what your `CompanyDetailsDataSet` is so i assume it implements `IEditableObject` interface. Otherwise you will have to do it on your own and ensure that old value is cached and retrieved on `CancelEdit()`

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox1.DataBinding.Add("Text",ds.Tables[0],"ColumnName")
```

where `ds` is the object of DataSet and `[0]` is the number of table in dataset you can write the name of table in double codes in the place of 0 if your procedure returns more then one table...