# C# Approaches to accessing and displaying data from a table

Tags: sql, database, winforms, data-binding

I need to understand the merits of using one method over another.  To simplify the situation - I have a textbox.text that

needs to display a field from a database table.  Let's say I have a table: table1 with one column, col1.

I can either specify something like this,

```
a) textbox1.text = table1["col1"].Rows[1]
```

OR

```
b) textbox1.DataBindings.Add() method
```

Can someone give me a comparison of these two alternatives, under what circumstances should I use one method over another?  Are there any others I should be aware of?  I know of LINQ, but understand that more like an alternative to SQL.

One further aspect that I do not understand.  If I wanted to populate ten textboxes with data from the table, I might use something like:

```
for (int i =0; i<10; i++)
{
Textbox[i].Text = table1["col1"].Rows[i];
}
```

How would this be accomplished using approach (b)/databinding?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It is `table1.Rows[i]["col1"];`

Comment: Databindings are a higher-level abstraction than just pushing data everywhere. I like them better (not from WinForms (also why are you still on WinForms) but from other frameworks that utilise the approach) because they make it easier to see the connection between the value of a GUI component and the underlying model. That is, you usually set up bindings in one place, instead of having GUI updates that are potentially scattered. The disadvantage, as is usual with higher levels of abstraction, is the cognitive overhead involved with less straightforward code.

Comment: @millimoose _'cognitive overhead'_ I like that....

Comment: @Steve The concept is an elegant explanation of why some people don't like frameworks. (Or why some frameworks are terrible.)

Comment: You have managed to explain in two words my dislike for ORM. At least until the discover of Dapper.

Comment: @FatCat - You could stuff the controls in a control array and use a `for` loop nested within a `foreach` loop to spin through the controls and add the databindings on-the-fly...

Comment: @FatCat or forget winforms and use a UI framework that supports (real) databinding.

Comment: Are you suggesting WPF?  What is the advantage of WPF databinding over winforms?  I have read that it is better but in what regard?

Answer (score 0):

Think of Databinding as "dynamic" in that the object you are bound to in the control will change if and when the data changes.  so the ideal binding situation is bind it once ( 2 way ) and forget about it.

In your other example the text is set and it will never change unless you explicitly change it and likewise if you need that text data you will have to access the text property and get the value back from the control.

Here is a good example in winforms.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11530/Understanding-Simple-Data-Binding

MS Binding Explained ( note 0 out of 6 vote )

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings.aspx

Another Stack Overflow Simple example

[C# Textbox data binding with DataSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717875/c-sharp-textbox-data-binding-with-dataset)